# What is the reason for Fermi surface nesting (FSN) in some materials?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

I wonder why some materials have perfect Fermi surface nesting (FSN) while some others have weak FSN or no nesting at all. Which factors of a given material determine the occurrence of FSN?